# Cross-validation for grouped time-series (panel) data

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, time-series, cross-validation, panel-data

I work with panel data: I observe a number of units (e.g. people) over time; for each unit, I have records for the same fixed time intervals.

When splitting the data into train and test sets, we need to make sure that both sets are disjoint and *sequential*, i.e. the latest records in the train set should be before the earliest records in the test set (see e.g. this [blog post](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/tscv/)).

Is there any standard Python implementation of cross-validation for panel data?

I've tried Scikit-Learn's [TimeSeriesSplit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit.html), which cannot account for groups, and [GroupShuffleSplit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GroupShuffleSplit.html) which cannot account for the sequential nature of the data, see code below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import GroupShuffleSplit, TimeSeriesSplit

# generate panel data
user = np.repeat(np.arange(10), 12)
time = np.tile(pd.date_range(start='2018-01-01', periods=12, freq='M'), 10)
data = (pd.DataFrame({'user': user, 'time': time})
        .sort_values(['time', 'user'])
        .reset_index(drop=True))

tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=4)
for train_idx, test_idx in tscv.split(data):
    train = data.iloc[train_idx]
    test = data.iloc[test_idx]
    train_end = train.time.max().date()
    test_start = test.time.min().date()
    print('TRAIN:', train_end, '\tTEST:', test_start, '\tSequential:', train_end < test_start, sep=' ')
```

Output:

```
TRAIN: 2018-03-31   TEST: 2018-03-31    Sequential: False
TRAIN: 2018-05-31   TEST: 2018-05-31    Sequential: False
TRAIN: 2018-08-31   TEST: 2018-08-31    Sequential: False
TRAIN: 2018-10-31   TEST: 2018-10-31    Sequential: False
```

So, in this example, I want the train and test sets to still be sequential.

There are a number of related, older posts, but with no (convincing) answer, see e.g.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51861417/time-series-prediction-for-grouped-data [now deleted]
- [Stratified Cross validation of timeseries data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46698792/stratified-cross-validation-of-timeseries-data)

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do. TimeSeriesSplit will always do sequential splits. In that it may happen that same date (only a single date in each fold) may be on both sides. Do you just want the train or test size to be adjusted so that the split always happen from next date? Its not related to GroupShuffleSplit in my opinion. Can you give an example of what you want?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, see updated question. Yes, train/test sets should not overlap in time when inputting panel data (repeated time measurements).

Comment: Well, there is not anything in scikit-learn to do this. But this should not be difficult to do in my opinion. You can manully group by the data by time and then split. Then just change the indices of the date according to your original data.

Answer (score 12):

This feature was requested on scikit-learn and I have added a [PR](https://github.com/getgaurav2/scikit-learn/blob/d4a3af5cc9da3a76f0266932644b884c99724c57/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py#L2243) for it  .
This technique was used with awesome results on some recent [Kaggle Notebooks](https://www.kaggle.com/search?q=getgaurav2) .

- scikit-learn Feature Request
  : https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/14257
- scikit-learn PR :
  https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/16236
- [Kaggle Notebook 1](https://www.kaggle.com/jorijnsmit/found-the-holy-grail-grouptimeseriessplit) Code block below
- [Kaggle Notebook 2](https://www.kaggle.com/marketneutral/purged-time-series-cv-xgboost-optuna/) ( Purged Time Series CV)  : This is an excellent modification with `gap` parameter between different groups . [Feature Request](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/19072) for the same has been raised on Scikit-learn .
- [Kaggle Notebook 3](https://www.kaggle.com/code/konradb/ts-10-validation-methods-for-time-series) : Summarizes all the methods very clearly.

```
from sklearn.model_selection._split import _BaseKFold, indexable, _num_samples
from sklearn.utils.validation import _deprecate_positional_args

# https://github.com/getgaurav2/scikit-learn/blob/d4a3af5cc9da3a76f0266932644b884c99724c57/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py#L2243
class GroupTimeSeriesSplit(_BaseKFold):
    """Time Series cross-validator variant with non-overlapping groups.
    Provides train/test indices to split time series data samples
    that are observed at fixed time intervals according to a
    third-party provided group.
    In each split, test indices must be higher than before, and thus shuffling
    in cross validator is inappropriate.
    This cross-validation object is a variation of :class:`KFold`.
    In the kth split, it returns first k folds as train set and the
    (k+1)th fold as test set.
    The same group will not appear in two different folds (the number of
    distinct groups has to be at least equal to the number of folds).
    Note that unlike standard cross-validation methods, successive
    training sets are supersets of those that come before them.
    Read more in the :ref:`User Guide <cross_validation>`.
    Parameters
    ----------
    n_splits : int, default=5
        Number of splits. Must be at least 2.
    max_train_size : int, default=None
        Maximum size for a single training set.
    Examples
    --------
    >>> import numpy as np
    >>> from sklearn.model_selection import GroupTimeSeriesSplit
    >>> groups = np.array(['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a',\
                           'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b',\
                           'c', 'c', 'c', 'c',\
                           'd', 'd', 'd'])
    >>> gtss = GroupTimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=3)
    >>> for train_idx, test_idx in gtss.split(groups, groups=groups):
    ...     print("TRAIN:", train_idx, "TEST:", test_idx)
    ...     print("TRAIN GROUP:", groups[train_idx],\
                  "TEST GROUP:", groups[test_idx])
    TRAIN: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] TEST: [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    TRAIN GROUP: ['a' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'a']\
    TEST GROUP: ['b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b']
    TRAIN: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] TEST: [11, 12, 13, 14]
    TRAIN GROUP: ['a' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b']\
    TEST GROUP: ['c' 'c' 'c' 'c']
    TRAIN: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]\
    TEST: [15, 16, 17]
    TRAIN GROUP: ['a' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'c' 'c' 'c' 'c']\
    TEST GROUP: ['d' 'd' 'd']
    """
    @_deprecate_positional_args
    def __init__(self,
                 n_splits=5,
                 *,
                 max_train_size=None
                 ):
        super().__init__(n_splits, shuffle=False, random_state=None)
        self.max_train_size = max_train_size

    def split(self, X, y=None, groups=None):
        """Generate indices to split data into training and test set.
        Parameters
        ----------
        X : array-like of shape (n_samples, n_features)
            Training data, where n_samples is the number of samples
            and n_features is the number of features.
        y : array-like of shape (n_samples,)
            Always ignored, exists for compatibility.
        groups : array-like of shape (n_samples,)
            Group labels for the samples used while splitting the dataset into
            train/test set.
        Yields
        ------
        train : ndarray
            The training set indices for that split.
        test : ndarray
            The testing set indices for that split.
        """
        if groups is None:
            raise ValueError(
                "The 'groups' parameter should not be None")
        X, y, groups = indexable(X, y, groups)
        n_samples = _num_samples(X)
        n_splits = self.n_splits
        n_folds = n_splits + 1
        group_dict = {}
        u, ind = np.unique(groups, return_index=True)
        unique_groups = u[np.argsort(ind)]
        n_samples = _num_samples(X)
        n_groups = _num_samples(unique_groups)
        for idx in np.arange(n_samples):
            if (groups[idx] in group_dict):
                group_dict[groups[idx]].append(idx)
            else:
                group_dict[groups[idx]] = [idx]
        if n_folds > n_groups:
            raise ValueError(
                ("Cannot have number of folds={0} greater than"
                 " the number of groups={1}").format(n_folds,
                                                     n_groups))
        group_test_size = n_groups // n_folds
        group_test_starts = range(n_groups - n_splits * group_test_size,
                                  n_groups, group_test_size)
        for group_test_start in group_test_starts:
            train_array = []
            test_array = []
            for train_group_idx in unique_groups[:group_test_start]:
                train_array_tmp = group_dict[train_group_idx]
                train_array = np.sort(np.unique(
                                      np.concatenate((train_array,
                                                      train_array_tmp)),
                                      axis=None), axis=None)
            train_end = train_array.size
            if self.max_train_size and self.max_train_size < train_end:
                train_array = train_array[train_end -
                                          self.max_train_size:train_end]
            for test_group_idx in unique_groups[group_test_start:
                                                group_test_start +
                                                group_test_size]:
                test_array_tmp = group_dict[test_group_idx]
                test_array = np.sort(np.unique(
                                              np.concatenate((test_array,
                                                              test_array_tmp)),
                                     axis=None), axis=None)
            yield [int(i) for i in train_array], [int(i) for i in test_array]
```

Example with GridSearchCV . Code modified from SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46732748/how-do-i-use-a-timeseriessplit-with-a-gridsearchcv-object-to-tune-a-model-in-sci).

```
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.model_selection import  GridSearchCV
import numpy as np
groups = np.array(['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'])

X = np.array([[4, 5, 6, 1, 0, 2], [3.1, 3.5, 1.0, 2.1, 8.3, 1.1]]).T
y = np.array([1, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3])

model = xgb.XGBRegressor()
param_search = {'max_depth' : [3, 5]}

tscv = GroupTimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=2)
gsearch = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, cv=tscv,
                        param_grid=param_search)
gsearch.fit(X, y , groups=groups)
```

Comment: Same as for @Kuba_'s answer: How can I implement your solution to GridSearchCV()? I can't initiate the class giving it a group parameter (date index).

Comment: @TiTo- Added  a code snippet above.

Comment: This is excellent.  I know sklearn is resisting full compatibility with pandas but seems like it would be trivial to wrap this to produce a groupby index from a time series or period index.   What I'm trying to do is to produce a walk forward cross validation similar to this medium post https://medium.com/eatpredlove/time-series-cross-validation-a-walk-forward-approach-in-python-8534dd1db51a and hyndman guidance but using the time index (in my case part of multi-level index) as the split.

Comment: @GauravChawla any update on this topic ? how is your PR going ? facing the same issue as the OP. Can I stiil use the code u shared here os it it out of date ?

Comment: @Miguel - The PR is still open.  The code on the PR and this post has diverged but the code snippet in the post here should be good on its own .

Answer (score 9):

I have recently hit the same task and after I failed to find appropriate solution I decided to write my own class which is a tweaked version of scikit-learn `TimeSeriesSplit` implementation. Therefore, I'll leave here for whoever comes later looking for the solution.

The idea is basically to sort the `data` by `time`, group the observations according to `time` variable and then just build cross-validator the same way `TimeSeriesSplit` does, but on the newly formed groups of observations.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.utils import indexable
from sklearn.utils.validation import _num_samples
from sklearn.model_selection._split import _BaseKFold

class GroupTimeSeriesSplit(_BaseKFold):
    """
    Time Series cross-validator for a variable number of observations within the time 
    unit. In the kth split, it returns first k folds as train set and the (k+1)th fold 
    as test set. Indices can be grouped so that they enter the CV fold together.

    Parameters
    ----------
    n_splits : int, default=5
        Number of splits. Must be at least 2.
    max_train_size : int, default=None
        Maximum size for a single training set.
    """
    def __init__(self, n_splits=5, *, max_train_size=None):
        super().__init__(n_splits, shuffle=False, random_state=None)
        self.max_train_size = max_train_size

    def split(self, X, y=None, groups=None):
        """
        Generate indices to split data into training and test set.

        Parameters
        ----------
        X : array-like of shape (n_samples, n_features)
            Training data, where n_samples is the number of samples and n_features is 
            the number of features.
        y : array-like of shape (n_samples,)
            Always ignored, exists for compatibility.
        groups : array-like of shape (n_samples,)
            Group labels for the samples used while splitting the dataset into 
            train/test set.
            Most often just a time feature.

        Yields
        -------
        train : ndarray
            The training set indices for that split.
        test : ndarray
            The testing set indices for that split.
        """
        n_splits = self.n_splits
        X, y, groups = indexable(X, y, groups)
        n_samples = _num_samples(X)
        n_folds = n_splits + 1
        indices = np.arange(n_samples)
        group_counts = np.unique(groups, return_counts=True)[1]
        groups = np.split(indices, np.cumsum(group_counts)[:-1])
        n_groups = _num_samples(groups)
        if n_folds > n_groups:
            raise ValueError(
                ("Cannot have number of folds ={0} greater"
                 " than the number of groups: {1}.").format(n_folds, n_groups))
        test_size = (n_groups // n_folds)
        test_starts = range(test_size + n_groups % n_folds,
                            n_groups, test_size)
        for test_start in test_starts:
            if self.max_train_size:
                train_start = np.searchsorted(
                    np.cumsum(
                        group_counts[:test_start][::-1])[::-1] < self.max_train_size + 1, 
                        True)
                yield (np.concatenate(groups[train_start:test_start]),
                       np.concatenate(groups[test_start:test_start + test_size]))
            else:
                yield (np.concatenate(groups[:test_start]),
                       np.concatenate(groups[test_start:test_start + test_size]))
```

And applying it to OP example we get:

```
gtscv = GroupTimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=3)
for split_id, (train_id, val_id) in enumerate(gtscv.split(data, groups=data["time"])):
    print("Split id: ", split_id, "\n") 
    print("Train id: ", train_id, "\n", "Validation id: ", val_id)
    print("Train dates: ", data.loc[train_id, "time"].unique(), "\n", "Validation dates: ", data.loc[val_id, "time"].unique(), "\n")

Split id:  0 

Train id:  [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
 24 25 26 27 28 29] 
 Validation id:  [30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53
 54 55 56 57 58 59]
Train dates:  ['2018-01-31T00:00:00.000000000' '2018-02-28T00:00:00.000000000'
 '2018-03-31T00:00:00.000000000'] 
 Validation dates:  ['2018-04-30T00:00:00.000000000' '2018-05-31T00:00:00.000000000'
 '2018-06-30T00:00:00.000000000'] 

Split id:  1 

Train id:  [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47
 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59] 
 Validation id:  [60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83
 84 85 86 87 88 89]
Train dates:  ['2018-01-31T00:00:00.000000000' '2018-02-28T00:00:00.000000000'
 '2018-03-31T00:00:00.000000000' '2018-04-30T00:00:00.000000000'
 '2018-05-31T00:00:00.000000000' '2018-06-30T00:00:00.000000000'] 
 Validation dates:  ['2018-07-31T00:00:00.000000000' '2018-08-31T00:00:00.000000000'
 '2018-09-30T00:00:00.000000000'] 

Split id:  2 

Train id:  [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47
 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71
 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89] 
 Validation id:  [ 90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107
 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119]
Train dates:  ['2018-01-31T00:00:00.000000000' '2018-02-28T00:00:00.000000000'
 '2018-03-31T00:00:00.000000000' '2018-04-30T00:00:00.000000000'
 '2018-05-31T00:00:00.000000000' '2018-06-30T00:00:00.000000000'
 '2018-07-31T00:00:00.000000000' '2018-08-31T00:00:00.000000000'
 '2018-09-30T00:00:00.000000000'] 
 Validation dates:  ['2018-10-31T00:00:00.000000000' '2018-11-30T00:00:00.000000000'
 '2018-12-31T00:00:00.000000000']
```

Comment: How can I implement your solution to `GridSearchCV()`? I can't initiate the class giving it a group parameter (date index).